# Error while building/running ubuntu-minimal image

Tags: 18.04, bash, docker, ubuntu-minimal

I'm seeing below error while running ubuntu-docker image that I built using following Dockerfile. Need some advice what am I missing here:

Dockerfile :

```
FROM scratch ADD https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/bionic/current/ubuntu-bionic-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz / ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

$ **docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash d36318a56ad3**

> /usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: invalid header
> field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting
> contaiused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or
> directory"\n".

Answer (score 0):

instead of using https link to the tar.gz file

download the tar.gz file locally

and do an add with the local file

```
wget https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/bionic/current/ubuntu-bionic-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz
```

and Dockerfile starts with

```
FROM scratch
ADD ubuntu-bionic-core-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz /
```

Comment: docker ADD untars the file only if it's local : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add - quote "if <src> is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory. Resources from remote URLs are not decompressed. "